# Android Native UI Component Not showing in react native

Tags: android, react-native

Im trying to create Android Native UI Components for InMobi banner. when i try to create a UI module using class that extending SimpleViewManager of react its not showing any view on screen. but when i use  with Fragments works fine but my requirement is to show with fragment as Inmobi setup shows that banner will be shown if we show banner on UI thread

What i tried

I tried with android[fragment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android#2-create-a-fragment) and this will work fine but i dont want to use this coz i want to show this banner with my existing layouts.

As [InMobi Banner](https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/sdk-documentation/android-guidelines/banner-ads-for-android) documentation shows that Banner will only show on UI Thread. so i tried using Handler and runOnUiThread (React.bridge) but its not working and the layout is not showing

here's InMobiBannerClass which will extend RelativeLayout and banner Initialisation

What i need

I need to show this banner with my existing design.

i thinkn problem is UI Thread

and this is my InMobiBannerManager which extends SimpleViewManager

```
public class InMobiBannerManager extends SimpleViewManager<InMobiBannerClass> {

public static final String REACT_CLASS = "InMobibanner";
ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
public InMobiBannerManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
}
@Override
public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
}

@Override
protected InMobiBannerClass createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    return new InMobiBannerClass(reactContext);
}
}
```

And this is my INMObiBannerCLass

```
public class InMobiBannerClass extends RelativeLayout  {
Context context;
InMobiBanner bannerAd;

BannerAdEventListener bannerAdEventListener = new BannerAdEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdFetchFailed(@NonNull InMobiBanner inMobiBanner, @NonNull InMobiAdRequestStatus inMobiAdRequestStatus) {
        super.onAdFetchFailed(inMobiBanner, inMobiAdRequestStatus);
        Log.d(TAG, "INMOBIBANNNERonAdFetchFailed: "+inMobiAdRequestStatus.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdDisplayed(@NonNull InMobiBanner inMobiBanner) {
        super.onAdDisplayed(inMobiBanner);
        Log.d(TAG, "INMOBIBANNNERonAdDisplayed: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdDismissed(@NonNull InMobiBanner inMobiBanner) {
        super.onAdDismissed(inMobiBanner);
        Log.d(TAG, "INMOBIBANNNERonAdDismissed: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserLeftApplication(@NonNull InMobiBanner inMobiBanner) {
        super.onUserLeftApplication(inMobiBanner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardsUnlocked(@NonNull InMobiBanner inMobiBanner, Map<Object, Object> map) {
        super.onRewardsUnlocked(inMobiBanner, map);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFetchSuccessful(@NonNull InMobiBanner inMobiBanner, @NonNull AdMetaInfo adMetaInfo) {
        super.onAdFetchSuccessful(inMobiBanner, adMetaInfo);
        Log.d(TAG, "onAdFetchSuccessful: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoadSucceeded(@NonNull InMobiBanner inMobiBanner, @NonNull AdMetaInfo adMetaInfo) {
        super.onAdLoadSucceeded(inMobiBanner, adMetaInfo);
        Log.d(TAG, "INMOBIBANNNERonAdLoadSucceeded: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoadFailed(@NonNull InMobiBanner inMobiBanner, @NonNull InMobiAdRequestStatus inMobiAdRequestStatus) {
        super.onAdLoadFailed(inMobiBanner, inMobiAdRequestStatus);
        Log.d(TAG, "INMOBIBANNNERonAdLoadFailed: "+inMobiAdRequestStatus.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(@NonNull InMobiBanner inMobiBanner, Map<Object, Object> map) {
        super.onAdClicked(inMobiBanner, map);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPayloadCreated(byte[] bytes) {
        super.onRequestPayloadCreated(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPayloadCreationFailed(@NonNull InMobiAdRequestStatus inMobiAdRequestStatus) {
        super.onRequestPayloadCreationFailed(inMobiAdRequestStatus);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdImpression(@NonNull InMobiBanner inMobiBanner) {
        super.onAdImpression(inMobiBanner);
    }
};
@SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
public InMobiBannerClass(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main3, null);
    RelativeLayout adContainer = (RelativeLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.ad_container);
    bannerAd = new InMobiBanner(context, 1683264304035L);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bannerLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx(350), dpToPx(200));

    adContainer.addView(bannerAd, bannerLp);

    bannerAd.setListener(bannerAdEventListener);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {



            bannerAd.setEnableAutoRefresh(true);

            bannerAd.load();

        } // Code that needs to be run on the main thread. })

    },1000);
    addView(inflatedView);
}
private int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}

public void onReceiveNativeEvent() {
    WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
    event.putString("message", "MyMessage");
    ReactContext reactContext = (ReactContext)getContext();
    reactContext
            .getJSModule(RCTEventEmitter.class)
            .receiveEvent(getId(), "topChange", event);
}
```

}

in React native
const InMobibanner = requireNativeComponent('InMobibanner');

Thanks in advance

Comment: Load is going to make an asynchronous network call.  It should not be run on the UI thread.

Comment: @GabeSechan can you please suggest me what should i do

Comment: Can you share the logs related to InMobi